# PRAGMA foreign_key_check;

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to use `PRAGMA foreign_key_check;` without success :(

I have made some foreign keys violations on a database (with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;`), then I set this to true then launched `PRAGMA foreign_key_check;` but this did not return any results.

However, when I try to insert the very same lines with foreign keys violations with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` I do get a foreign key constraint violation error.

I am using SQLite 3.7.3.

Is there something I am missing regarding this command? Is there a bug?

Thanks

EDIT: I have just tried with 3.8.3.1 (higher version this time ;) ) but cannot get any results though :(

However, some other commands seem to not work as expected (especially .schema !?):

```
SQLite version 3.8.3.1 2014-02-11 14:52:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> attach "D:\MusicLib_Minimal_TEST_FOREIGN_KEYS.db" as db1;
sqlite> .schema device
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
1
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_key_check;
sqlite> select * from device
   ...> ;
1|test|/|/|0|0
sqlite> select * from playlist
   ...> ;
sqlite> PRAGMA integrity_check;
ok
sqlite> .dump device
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
COMMIT;
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(device);
0|idDevice|INTEGER|1||1
1|name|TEXT|1||0
2|source|TEXT|1||0
3|destination|TEXT|1||0
4|idPlaylist|INTEGER|1||0
5|idMachine|INTEGER|1||0
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 5):

`PRAGMA foreign_key_check` was [added in sqlite 3.7.16](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_16.html). You have [an older version](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_3.html).

Unknown pragmas are just no-ops; no errors are emitted.

Comment: "I am using SQLite 3.7.3.", that's newer than 3.7.16, no ?

Comment: D'oh ... that's right ! :-( Thanks for pointing this! I've read about this 3.7.16 addition but thought (with no reason) that it was foreign keys feature that was added to that version and as those worked I supposed I had proper version ...

Comment: I have edited my question now that I have tried with 3.8.3.1 and still the same problem. Could you please have a look ?

Comment: @RaphaelCamus Something with the data that is not shown in the updated question. When I cook up my own test data, `PRAGMA foreign_key_check` works as advertised.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I found out the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the solution :) Problem was a misuse (or bug ?) of sqlite3.exe

When calling sqlite3.exe without parameters, a main empty database is created, and looks like the commands does not apply the attached db:

```
D:\>sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.8.3.1 2014-02-11 14:52:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> attach "D:\MusicLib_Minimal_TEST_FOREIGN_KEYS.db" as db1
   ...> ;
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file

---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------

0    main

2    db1              D:\MusicLib_Minimal_TEST_FOREIGN_KEYS.db
sqlite> .tables
db1.device       db1.libType      db1.optiontype   db1.playlist
db1.file         db1.machine      db1.path         db1.statement
db1.genre        db1.option       db1.playCounter  db1.statsource
sqlite> .schema db1.device
sqlite> .exit
```

If opening database as an argument of sqlite3.exe, it works as expected:

```
D:\>sqlite3.exe MusicLib_Minimal_TEST_FOREIGN_KEYS.db
SQLite version 3.8.3.1 2014-02-11 14:52:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file

---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------

0    main             D:\MusicLib_Minimal_TEST_FOREIGN_KEYS.db

sqlite> .tables
device       genre        machine      optiontype   playCounter  statement
file         libType      option       path         playlist     statsource
sqlite> .schema device
CREATE TABLE "device" (
    "idDevice" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "source" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "destination" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "idPlaylist" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "idMachine" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(idPlaylist) REFERENCES playlist(idPlaylist),
    FOREIGN KEY(idMachine) REFERENCES machine(idMachine)
);
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
0
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
1
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_key_check;
device|1|machine|0
device|1|playlist|1
sqlite> select * from device
   ...> ;
1|test|/|/|0|0
sqlite> select * from playlist
   ...> ;
sqlite> select * from machine
   ...> ;
```